# Read excel file (pd.read_excel()) by skipping blank rows only

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe as below.

```
    id       date       name    branch  position
0   20323   2019-02-03  Bete    H       IE
1   20326   2019-02-03  Veso    R       MGR
2   22357   2019-02-03  Nom     D       IE
3   20935   2019-02-06  Dow     A       MGR
4   NaN     NaT         NaN     NaN     NaN
5   20432   2019-02-07  Tem     W       MGR
6   23999   NaT         Bonny   NaN     NaN
7   21102   2019-02-07  Xi      A       IE
```

I want to remove the blank rows only(ex: index 4).

I tried to read the data file using `df = pd.read_excel("../20191210/test.xlsx", skip_blank_lines=True)`.

But there is no different from the result of `df = pd.read_excel("..20191210/test.xlsx")`

[Here](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/6507cc151b4404cd4df9eda3e10d831a20191211121010/d50bb8c9630734b1bcbc3301046bacbf20191211121010/b8f801) is the download link to the file.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: I think with df.dropna(how='all') is enough

Comment: How are we supposed to help with reading a file from Excel without any data or the file itself?

Comment: @AlexanderCécile Sorry! I added the URL to download the file

Answer (score 10):

Here a example with df.dropna(how='all') : Without NaN if all rows have NaN

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dict = {'Col1':[100, 90, np.nan, 95],
        'Col2': [30, 45, np.nan, np.nan],
        'Col3':[np.nan, 40,np.nan, 98]}

df = pd.DataFrame(dict)
# With NaN
print(df)

# Without NaN
df = df.dropna()
print (df)

# Without NaN if all rows have NaN
df = df.dropna(how='all')
print (df)
```

Comment: ```df.dropna(how='all')``` is working. Is there any way to skip rows while reading?

Comment: @Akira I'm googling

Comment: in your excel , NaN value is null ? N/A ?,,,is blank ?

Comment: I added blank rows for testing

Comment: I'm afraid that no...
I could not find some like you want....I hope the code that I gave you could be util

Answer (score 1):

Try `df = df.dropna()` after reading the excel file.

Comment: ```df.dropna()``` drops index 6.

Comment: I think this will help: ```df = df.dropna(subset=['id'])```